# I need help understanding how to sort a set or vector with multiple strings with spaces in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, maps, fstream

I am attempting to take in a text file with "stock market tickers" taken from multiple points in the day.

I.E.

Ticker Price
HPQ 121
MSFT 76
X 133
EBAY 92
XOM 64
AAPL 141
DJIA 128
AAPL 130
ABC 139
ABC 102
DJIA 121
HPQ 121
DJIA 96
XOM 130
MSFT 132
HPQ 129
HPQ 71
GOOG 142
MSFT 67
X 70

I need to take in those values, remove the duplicates and display the closing values in alphabetical order. So far I have this...

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <string>
 #include <vector>
 #include <map>
 using namespace std;

 int main()
{
string filename;
map<string, int> string_count;
vector<string> market_list;

ifstream data_store;

//cout << "Enter stock file name to analyze" << endl;
//cin >> filename;

//data_store.open(filename.c_str());
data_store.open("stock1.txt");

while(!data_store.eof())
{
    string element;
    //data_store >> element;
    getline(data_store, element);
    //Remove ticker price from list
    if(element != "Ticker Price")
    {
        string_count[element]++;
    }
}
map<string, int>::iterator map_iter;
for(map_iter = string_count.begin(); map_iter != string_count.end(); map_iter++)
{
    market_list.push_back(map_iter->first);
}

data_store.close();

ofstream output_file;
output_file.open("stock_result.txt");

output_file << "Latest prices: " << endl;

vector<string>::iterator iter;
for (iter = market_list.begin(); iter != market_list.end(); iter++)
{
    string the_element = *iter;
    int num_times_repeated = string_count[the_element];
    for(int x = 0; x< num_times_repeated; x++)
    {
        output_file << the_element << endl;
    }
}

output_file.close();
}
```

which outputs all values of the file alphabetically, without removing anything. I understand why this is, but I am having a hard time getting around how to set this up for what I want. Keep in mind, I am a student so I don't want a straight forward answer :)

*Edit*

I want my code to take in the list above and output the "closing" values, which is the final value of each ticker and display them alphabetically

So the result would be

Latest prices:
ABC 102
AAPL 130
DJIA 96
and so on.

Comment: Don't use `while (!data_store.eof())`, use `while (getline(data_store, element))`.

Comment: I don't understand the question. "I understand why this is but I am having a hard time getting around how to set 'this' up for what I want"?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::map<std::string,int> stocks;
std::string symbol, line;
int value;
while (getline(data_store,line))
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    if (iss >> symbol >> value)
        stocks[symbol] = value;
}
```

Then just iterator over stocks.

Comment: Thank you so much! Both you and @Prototype Stark really helped me understand how to do this. I ended up making the map you showed, and made a set as well.

Answer (score 1):

To remove duplicates, please look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/ . This container only stores "Unique" values. Hence it will remove the duplicates.

Comment: The problem with this is if I pass in both the ticker and number with getline(), None of them would be a duplicate. If I separate the integer from the string, it would remove the duplicate strings and integers, but how would I keep track of the integer matching the strings?

Comment: use data_store >> company >> stock; and then store it in a set using the company's name.